# How to change values in a compiled apk?

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to create an app in which I want to change some values like some colors which are located in **res/values/colors.xml**. I want to create a patch file which will be able to modify my app later.

Basically, I am making an app lock where I want to update the lock screen later with different kind of backgrounds and change the colors of buttons and texts.

For example: See CM AppLock. Where the user is able to download the theme from the play store and install it and the lock screen changes as per the theme.

Comment: You cannot change an APK on the device because the signature would no longer be valid. You need to find a way to implement this without changing the APK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way CM AppLock does it is called "**Android Runtime Resource Overlay**", aka **RRO**. Here is a [brief Introduction](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/2tooz7/an_explanation_of_rro_runtime_resource_overlay/) of **RRO**. The mainstream Android releases have **RRO** enabled for preinstalled packages(not allowed for downloadable apks). Last I checked the patches for RRO for downloadable apks are still in [review](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/q/RRO). Android O will most likely have this feature. Here is a brief [overview](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-preparing-enable-custom-themes-built-on-sony-rro-framework/) of this new feature coming in Android O.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Can you send me some links where can I learn about **RRO**.

Comment: I have included some links in the answer itself. Those links have a lot more links in them. You should have a lot of reading material. It is currently only allowed for vendor pre-installed packages. If you are burning your own ROM, then you can possibly bypass that restriction. Also there are some corner cases where RRO does not work as expected. If this does not scare you, then the reading the patches on [android code review site](https://android-review.googlesource.com/) will give you a lot of information

Comment: As you said that **It is currently only allowed for vendor pre-installed packages** then how does CM AppLock use that.

Comment: CM has merged some of the RRO code into their source and possibly enhanced it. I will try to post the links to their source